# nginx hotlink protection for missing referer, but allow direct URL request

Tags: nginx, http-headers, hotlinking

I'm using the following hotlink protection for Nginx I found from this page:

https://nixcp.com/anti-hotlinking-nginx/

I use this code:

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp|svg|ico)$ {

valid_referers none blocked mysite.com ~.mysite.com server_names ~($host);
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return  403;
    } 
}
```

When I remove "none" from the valid_referers to prevent pages that hotlink without referer, I noticed this also affects direct URL requests from browser URL bar.

My question is: **is there any way to block websites that hotlink and send requests with the “Referer” field is missing in the request header; but at the same time allow direct URL requests from the browser?**

Thanks!

Comment: Direct requests are the only case when there is no referrer. What case are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Well, some pages are hotlinking my images sending requests with missing referers. I want to block those pages, but at the same time be able to request any image URL by the browser if I need to.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider a website can hotlink without referrer this way: <img referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="https://images.yoursite.com/img.png">